# Changing the style of a polygon layer using PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, style

I can change the style of point layers and line layers, but not polygon layers. How can I do this?

```
# This works to change the style of a point layer:
symbol = QgsMarkerSymbol.createSimple({"color": "orange", "size": "1"})
pointlayer.setRenderer(QgsSingleSymbolRenderer(symbol))
pointlayer.triggerRepaint()

# This works to change the style of a line layer:
symbol = QgsLineSymbol.createSimple({"color": "red", "width": "1"})
linelayer.setRenderer(QgsSingleSymbolRenderer(symbol))
linelayer.triggerRepaint()

# This doesn't work to change the style of a polygon layer:
symbol = QgsFillSymbol.createSimple({"color": "red", "outline_color": "red"})
ellipselayer.setRenderer(QgsSingleSymbolRenderer(symbol))
ellipselayer.triggerRepaint()
```

Comment: Maybe you need to add some more details or share a test layer on which it doesn't work, because I can't reproduce your problem. The snippet you are using works fine for me with a polygon layer.